# fill combobox windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I try fill a `ComboBox` using the entity framework 
so I try this:

```
public home()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SMSEntities sms = new SMSEntities();
    Item_head.DataSource = sms.spget_head().ToString().ToList();
    Item_head.DisplayMember = "S_stockhead";
    Item_head.ValueMember = "S_stockhead_id";

}
```

but this shows error on this line:  `Item_head.ValueMember = "S_stockhead";`

error:

> Cannot bind to the new display member

Comment: `sms.spget_head().ToString().ToList()`? What's this? Make sure the returned object has *properties* instead of fields.

Comment: Please post your the code for your models - this will help. S_stockhead needs to be a property your POCO,

Comment: please remove `().ToString().ToList();` and leave only `Item_head.DataSource = sms.spget_head();` you scrumbled your list and the `ComboBox` cannot find the property `S_stockhead` because it is of another type than initially.

Answer (score 0):

What does the function `sms.spget_head()` returns? I may be wrong but using `ToString()` on object ends with returning its name as string. Function `ToList` used with string does split string into characters. Then u probably cannot set display/value member as you would to.
Im binding entity datasource like that :

```
cbxCity.DataSource = MyContainer.Cities.ToList();
cbxCity.DisplayMember = "name";
cbxCity.ValueMember = "id";
```

Comment: what is mycontainer?

Comment: `MyContainer` is Entity Data Model. Cities is `DbSet<>`.